# How can I call a vb.net program from a unix shell script

Tags: vb.net, unix, aix

I need to be able to kick off a vb.net program on a windows server from a unix shell script on an AIX server.  What what I need to do to make this possible?  I'm a newbie on the .Net side, but I was thinking, maybe make the vb.net program some sort of web service then have the unix shell script invoke that somehow.  But don't know if I am on the right track.  Would appreciate any advice.  Thanks.

Comment: do you have control over the VB.Net program? I mean, if required, can you modify its source?

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows side, install PHP, then use the `exec()` function or its friends to start the vb.net program. Kick it off from AIX via `wget` or `curl`.

Alternativly use netcat for windows (`nc.exe`) if you are comfortable with the security implications.

Comment: what a strange idea... installing php to kick of program. Aas it's Windows, why not using out-of-the blox asp.net capabilities of IIS? or even a simple http self hosted listner ?

Comment: Because I know enough about the pros and cons of PHP's program execution facilities, but not about ASP.NET's. Another guy might give another answer, though.

Comment: It's quite easy using ASP.Net, a simple call to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)` can launch the program. There can be some security settings to be aware of, like process identity, but the idea is here.

Comment: Yes, Steve, I would have control of the VB.Net program.

Comment: I know about the `Process` class and use it extensivly - but I do NOT know enough of the process model, the security implications, etc. do be comfortable with using it to start an arbitrary program from inside IIS. You migth want to create an answer from your knowledge, this would surely be of interest to the OP!

Answer (score 0):

Several options are offered to you.

1. As suggested by Eugen Rieck, you can have a lightweight http application (using asp.net or php, but I think asp.net is more logic). The app will contain a very simple http handler that will fire the program using  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)`whenever the page is reached (beware of DOS attack). To reach the page, wget or curl will do the job (I trust Eugen for that, as I never wrote scripts in *nix)
2. You can modify your program to run as a service (or create a new one), this program can listen for "command" using whatever inter-operable technic you know. It can be a simple http listener, a WCF rest services, a message queue system, or even a file system monitor (listen for files drops in a folder).
3. reverse the logic (probably not applicable). Publish on the unix side a web page containing the work to do, and pool from the vb program this work.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, Steve. Let me look into this a bit.  I'll post back whatever the final solution ends up being.  Thanks for the advice everyone.